# SFML window Always intercept all events, causing other areas to lose response

Tags: c, sfml

https://github.com/kamirr/QSFML
I used this method to complete the Qt\SFML integration
But I found Once this control gains focus, the event can no longer be delivered to other parts of the program.

thanks for any help.